# Reference to generic function in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, closures

In Swift, you can create a reference to a function in the form of a closure. For example:

```
func simpleFunc(param: Int) {
    
}
let simpleFuncReference = simpleFunc(param:) // works just fine
```

But in one case, I have a function with a generic parameter like this:

```
func hardFunc<T: StringProtocol>(param: T) {
    
}
let hardFuncReference = hardFunc(param:) // "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
```

To try to remove that error, I attempted to explicitly specify the type, but immediately another error comes up.

```
func hardFunc<T: StringProtocol>(param: T) {
    
}
let hardFuncReference = hardFunc(param:) // "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"
```

Is there a way I can get a reference to `hardFunc` as a closure?

Comment: You can't create a generic closure, so it has to be a concrete function. This, for example, would work: `let hardFuncReference: (String) -> Void = hardFunc`

Comment: or `let hardFuncReference: (Substring) -> Void = hardFunc`

Comment: Amazing. I'm going to put this as an answer unless you'd like to write it up. I think it could help someone else later on

Comment: Lol... I just wrote an answer saying exactly this.  If one of those guys writes up the answer, accept theirs instead, since they gave you the answer in comments before I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already guessed, you have to help type inference out a little:

```swift
func hardFunc<T: StringProtocol>(param: T) {
    
}
let hardFuncReference:(String) -> Void  = hardFunc(param:)
```

Note that you do have to specify the particular type that you're specializing on, but in this case you do it by specifying the type of the variable you're assigning the closure to.

You can't keep it generic unless you're in a generic context specifying that it's generic on the same type.  So this will work too

```swift
struct Foo<T: StringProtocol> {
    let hardFuncReference:(T) -> Void  = hardFunc(param:)
}
```